# Passing output of one Evaluate statement to another. Getting Error 2015

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate

I'm able to get the first Evaluate function to work. But not the second one. It gives "Error 2015" in the second Evaluate for strBulkBP. Output of the first is being passed to the second function. Please help to fix the code.
Thanks.

```
Sub test1()

Dim strBulkNum as Variant
Dim strBulkBP As Variant

Set wksh3 = Workbooks("Master - Data.xlsx").Sheets("Data")
Set wksh4 = Workbooks("Warranty_Analysis.xlsm").Sheets("TTX-OWNER_data")

Set rngBulkNum = wksh3.Range("BulkNum") 'column A:A
Set rngRefNum = wksh3.Range("RefNum") 'column N:N

Set rngBPNum = wksh4.Range("BPNum") 'column A:A
Set rngBPBulkNum = wksh4.Range("BPBulkNum") 'column E:E

strRefNum = "ES80381"
' The code below works to give a value for strBulkNum = "MX12049"
strBulkNum = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX('[Master - Data.xlsx]Data'!" & rngBulkNum.Address(False, True) & ", SMALL(IF('[Master - Data.xlsx]Data'!" & rngRefNum.Address(False, True) & "=""" & strRefNum & """, ROW('[Master - Data.xlsx]Data'!" & rngRefNum.Address(False, True) & "))," & 2 & ")),"""")")

' The code below does not work. Gives "Error 2015" for strBulkBP
strBulkBP = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX('[Warranty_Analysis.xlsm]TTX-OWNER_data'!" & rngBPNum.Address(False, True) & ", SMALL(IF('[Warranty_Analysis.xlsm]TTX-OWNER_data'!" & rngBPBulkNum.Address(False, True) & "=""" & strBulkNum & """,ROW('[Warranty_Analysis.xlsm]TTX-OWNER_data'!" & rngBPBulkNum.Address(False, True) & "))," & 2 & ")),"""")")

'The below code works - using helper cells & then populating the variable
Set wkshCal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculation")
Dim FormulaPart1 As String 
Dim FormulaPart2 As String 

wkshCal.Range("A1") = strBulkNum
FormulaPart1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX('[Warranty_Analysis.xlsm]TTX-OWNER_data'!$A:$A, xxx()),"""")" 
FormulaPart2 = "SMALL(IF('[Warranty_Analysis.xlsm]TTX-OWNER_data'!$E:$E = $A$1, ROW('[Warranty_Analysis.xlsm]TTX-OWNER_data'!$E:$E)), 1)" 
With wkshCal.Range("B1") 
 .FormulaArray = FormulaPart1 
 .Replace "xxx()", FormulaPart2 
End With 
strBulkBP = Range("B1") 
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `Evaluate` for this instead of the equivalent VBA?

Comment: I need to store the value in a variable and use it after. Hence trying to use Evaluate method.

Comment: Do let me know the equivalent VBA code that would work. Thanks.

Comment: I just found out that I need to use Array function as the number of characters was exceeding 255. Even in Array function I needed to break the formula into two parts:

Comment: Dim FormulaPart1 As String
    Dim FormulaPart2 As String
    FormulaPart1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX('[Warranty_Analysis.xlsm]TTX-OWNER_data'!$A:$A, XXX()),"""")"
FormulaPart2 = "SMALL(IF('[Warranty_Analysis.xlsm]TTX-OWNER_data'!$E:$E = $A$1, ROW('[Warranty_Analysis.xlsm]TTX-OWNER_data'!$E:$E)), 1)"
With Range("B1")
    .FormulaArray = FormulaPart1
    .Replace "xxx()", FormulaPart2
End With
strBulkBP = Range("B1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'The below code works - using helper cells & then populating the variable. However the array formula needs to be split into two parts to make it less than 255 characters each. A better solution can be one where the variable directly stores the calculation.
    Set wkshCal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculation")
    Dim FormulaPart1 As String 
    Dim FormulaPart2 As String

```
wkshCal.Range("A1") = strBulkNum
FormulaPart1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX('[Warranty_Analysis.xlsm]TTX-OWNER_data'!$A:$A, xxx()),"""")" 
FormulaPart2 = "SMALL(IF('[Warranty_Analysis.xlsm]TTX-OWNER_data'!$E:$E = $A$1, ROW('[Warranty_Analysis.xlsm]TTX-OWNER_data'!$E:$E)), 1)" 
With wkshCal.Range("B1") 
 .FormulaArray = FormulaPart1 
 .Replace "xxx()", FormulaPart2 
End With 
strBulkBP = Range("B1")
```